# on change text not working for imported component

Tags: react-native

so i created and imported a component that is text input. however, it is not setting the text on change. any ideas?

```
<Email onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}/>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

function Email() {
  return (
    <TextInput
      label="Email"
      placeholder="Email"
      placeholderTextColor="black"
      style = {{ width: 310, padding:20, marginBottom:10, backgroundColor:"#ebecff", borderRadius:10 }}
    />
  );
}
export default Email;
```

Comment: What does you setEmail() function do?

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
function Email(props) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      ...
      onChangeText={text => props.onChangeText(text)} // add this code
    />
  );
}
```